# Can Groovy objects be invoked like functions with parameters?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

In Groovy, I can make an object invokable like a function by monkey-patching the metaclass' `call` method:

```
myObject.metaClass.call = { "hello world" }
println myObject() // prints "hello world"
```

patching `call` only allows me to invoke the object with no arguments. Is there a way of allowing objects to be invoked with arguments using standard function-like syntax?

---

**edit:** one answer is exactly as tim_yates suggests, although it's worth noting from ataylor's comment that you can simply override `call` without explicit metaprogramming:

```
class MyType {
    def call(...args) {
        "args were: $args"
    }
}

def myObject = new MyType()
println myObject("foo", "bar") // prints 'args were ["foo", "bar"]'
```

Apparently the trick is the variadic signature using `...args`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
myObject.metaClass.call = { ...args -> "hello $args" }
assert myObject( 'one', 'two', 'three' ) == 'hello [one, two, three]'
```

(as you can see, args is an array of Objects)

Or for one parameter:

```
myObject.metaClass.call = { who -> "hello $who" }
```

Or if you want that single parameter as an optional param, you could do:

```
myObject.metaClass.call = { who = null -> "hello ${who ?: 'world'}" }

assert myObject( 'tim' ) == 'hello tim'
assert myObject() == 'hello world'
```

Comment: hmm... I could have sworn that I tried this and it didn't work, but trying again seems to demonstrate that it does.

Comment: While the question is specifically about adding the behavior through the metaclass, it's worth noting this also works with a standard method named `call`, no metaprogramming required.